# Merging detached object deletes children

Tags: hibernate

My model looks like this(in real case there are getters and setters):

```
class Foo {
    Set<Bar> bars; 

    void attachBars(Set<Bar> bars){
        this.bars = bars;
        for(Bar bar : bars)
            bar.foo = this;
    }
}
class Bar {
    Set<Baz> bazes;  
}
class Baz {
}
```

Then I execute:

```
Foo foo = e.find(Foo.class, "id");
Hibernate.initialize(foo.bars);
em.detach(foo)

Foo foo2 = e.find(Foo.class, "id");
doSomeChanges(foo2);
foo2.attachBars(foo.bars);
```

What I see in debugger:

before `attachBars(foo.bars);` the `bar.bazes` fields are not accesible due to `LazyInitializationException`

after `attachBars(foo.bars);` ther `bar.bazes` fields are set to null, and after em.merge the bazes are removed from database.

Answer (score 0):

The `attachBars` method should never change the reference to this.bars. It would be/is arleady instantiated by *Hibernate*, because we retrived foo via `find()`, i.e. Hibernate session. Reference to this collection is essential, becuase only this way we can rely on proper dirty checking *(newly added, deleted items)*

So it should be like this *(expecting collection was instantiated by Hibernate)*:

```
void attachBars(Set<Bar> bars){
    if(this.bars == null){
      this.bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
    }
    for(Bar bar : bars){
        this.bars.add(bar);
        bar.foo = this;
    }
}
```

But in this case, that does not have to be enough. The passed colleciton `bars` is coming from detached object(s). Which does not have populated `bazes` collection at all.

Once they are reatteched to just loaded object, they could seem to have empty collections. So before we detache the root object, we should force intialization of all Baz instances as well.

Even better solution, I would suggest is to iterate the old bars collection and load by id the actual proxies

Comment: With additional bars.clear(), but ok. I will check if this was the problem.